# Real time output using login shell command from Python3

Tags: python, shell, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm trying to get the output of a subprocess to prompt for a login then continue with the rest of the script once logged in. I can get it to prompt for the login, but after entering my username and password I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./login.py", line 20, in <module>
    login()
  File "./login.py", line 13, in login
    output = login_cmd.stderr.read(1)
ValueError: read of closed file.
```

Below is the script:

```
import subprocess, sys

raidcom = '/usr/bin/raidcom'

def login(cmd=raidcom):
    login_cmd = subprocess.Popen('{cmd} -login'.format(cmd=cmd),
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    (output, err) = login_cmd.communicate()
    while True:
        output = login_cmd.stderr.read(1)
        if output == '' and login_cmd.poll() != None:
            break
        if output != '':
            sys.stdout.write(output)
            sys.stdout.flush()

login()
```

When I normally execute the command from the shell it returns nothing after logging in.

Comment: [`Popen.communicate`: Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. **Wait for process to terminate.**](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)

Comment: `output` is what your process wrote to stdout though it will be empty since you aren't redirecting stdout, `err` is what it wrote to `stderr`. You should avoid `shell=True` and instead have `subprocess.Popen([cmd, '-login'], stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another way around this situation. Instead of passing the real-time output I prompted for the the user's username and password information and inserted that information into the command. The below function works:

```
import subprocess
import getpass

raidcom = '/usr/bin/raidcom'

def raidcom_login(cmd=raidcom):
    """Login to CCI and return its output."""
    horcm_user = input("Please enter your username for logging into CCI: ")
    horcm_pass = getpass.getpass("Please enter your password: ")
    try:
        login_cmd = subprocess.check_output('{cmd} -login {} {}'.format(horcm_user, horcm_pass, cmd=cmd),
                                 stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print('Login failed')
```